# How to undo flagging?

Tags: support, user-interface, flagging

I've erroneously flagged [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/4020/41291) as spam (some anonymous user tried to edit it by seemingly injecting some spam and this confused me), how do I cancel my action?

Comment: I think you cannot undo a flag, but a single spam flag has no consequences for the flagged post (it takes 6 spam flags to delete).

Comment: @StefanKohl Thanks! Actually I now discovered in the related column that this is possibly a duplicate. I think I will remove this question.

Comment: Maybe. -- Though it can also be a useful pointer when closed as a duplicate (and not deleted), I think.